# Django Rename Column In Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have messed up my migrations and need to rename a column in my database, is that possible?
Im also using docker which means I can't use any graphical interface to change tables in my db.
If changing the column name isn't possible, maybe I could drop the hole table as there is no data saved on that table yet.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Using docker in no way precludes using the graphical interface [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Run `python manage.py dbshell`. Then you'll have a PostgreSQL shell open. From there you can run your postgres queries to rename a column to match your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename the field in the model you defined in Django, and then run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

In any case, when you want to delete a table you can use the python shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

And then:

```
from {name_of_your_app}.models import {name_of_your_model}
{name_of_your_model}.objects.all().delete()
```